# Could not understand java assert mechanism

Tags: java, assert

This program is a question in a book of SCJP questions

```
class One {
    int x = 0;
    {
        assert x == 1;
    }
}

public class Two {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int y = 0;
        assert y == 0;
        if(args.length > 0)
            new One();
    }
}
```

Which of the following will run without error?
Options given are

```
A. java Two
B. java Two x
C. java -ea Two
D. java -ea Two x
E. java -ea:One Two
F. java -ea:One Two x
G. java -ea:Two Two x
```

Correct options are A, B, C, E and G

Reason given for D and F to be incorrect is, instance of `One` is created. I don't understand why it would be a problem if an instance of `One` is created.

In option B and G also, instance of `One` is created, then why is it a problem for D and F?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand why it would be a problem if an instance of `One` is created.

Because `One` contains an `assert` that is guaranteed to fail when it is instantiated (and those options pass in `args`); `0 != 1` in

```
class One {
    int x = 0;
    {
        assert x == 1;
    }
}
```

Further, in option `B`  asserts are not enabled and in option `G` asserts are only enabled in class `Two` (and the problematic assert is in class `One`).

Answer (score 2):

In order for an assert to do anything it has to be enabled. A and B do not have assertions enabled at all. G only has them enabled for class `Two`.

D and F both have assertions enabled for class `One` and create an instance.